# Can BIRT be used on a standalone Swing/JavaFX desktop application?

Tags: swing, javafx, reporting, birt

I am new to Eclipse BIRT, and I've noticed that BIRT runs on a server, what I need to know is if it's possible to integrate BIRT into a stand-alone JavaFX/Swing Application which runs without a server, and call the `.rptdesing` file directly from my desktop application to generate a report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you add a dependency to the ReportEngine you can run the report from any Java program including A JavaFX or Swing application.

[Here is an example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Simple_Execute_(BIRT)_2.1) from the BIRT documentation on how to call the ReportEngine from a Java main method to generate a report from an existing `.rptdesign` report.